# Popup NSMenu on right-click on NSView (Swift)

Tags: swift, nsview, nsmenu

I subclassed a NSView to handle mouseDown/rightMouseDown events. Now i want to popUp a contextual NSMenu (which is a IBOutlet) by right-clicking.

```
NSMenu.popUpContextMenu(statusMenu, withEvent: theEvent, forView: self)
```

... but it says "statusMenu is not a member of AppDelegate". How can i access vars outside the class?

EDIT:

The IBOutlet ist located in the AppDelegate:

```
@IBOutlet weak var statusMenu: NSMenu!
```

I try to call it from my custom NSView:

```
class customView : NSView { 
  override func rightMouseDown(theEvent : NSEvent) {
    // NSMenu.popUpContextMenu ???
  }
}
```

Comment: Where is the IBOutlet - in the NSView or in the AppDelegate? And where are you making the call from (I assume the NSView)?  Also, I assume the dot in `.self` is a typo...

Comment: I edited my post above. You're right, the IBOutlet is located in the AppDelegate. I tried to call the NSMenu out of my subclassed NSView.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are various ways you could do this:

1) Create an IBOutlet in your `NSView` and connect the `NSMenu` to it.

2) Create an IBOutlet in your `NSView`, connect your `AppDelegate` to it, and refer to the menu through that outlet (if you didn't want for some reason to have two references to the menu)

3) Get a runtime reference to the AppDelegate in the `NSView` - the syntax is

`var appDelegate = NSApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as AppDelegate`

and refer to the menu through that.

Note that in case 3 "AppDelegate" is whatever name your AppDelegate class actually is (usually, but not necessarily, "AppDelegate"). The same is true for the type of the IBOutlet in case 2.

Comment: I wasn't able to create an IBOutlet inside of the subclassed NSView `class customView : NSView {}`. But the third solution solved my problem! Thank you so much.